# Assertion 'GDK_IS_DISPLAY (display)' failed - Cannot decide type for the following arguments: data

Tags: python, opencv, deep-learning, computer-vision, mxnet

I'm doing a vehicle tracking and counting program. I encounter an error when I try to run this block of code:

```
import mxnet
import gluoncv as gcv
import cv2.cv2 as cv2
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import math
import numpy as np
import gluoncv.data.transforms.image as image
import time

def main():
    ctx = mxnet.gpu(1)
    # This bunch of codes used to recognise specific classes

    classes = ["Motorbike", "Car/Van"]
    net = gcv.model_zoo.get_model("ssd_512_resnet50_v1_voc", pretrained=True, ctx=ctx)
    net.reset_class(classes)
    net.load_parameters("vehicle_best.params")

    cap = cv2.VideoCapture("tang2ngay3_10video2.mp4")
    out = cv2.VideoWriter("result_video.mp4", 0x7634706d, 30.0, (910, 512))

    frame_number = 0
    counting_point = 750
    nof_vehicle = [0] * len(classes)
    tracks_active = []
    start = time.time()
    while (cap.isOpened()):

        ret, frame = cap.read()

        if ret == False:
            break
        # if frame_number == 100:
        #     break


        frame = mxnet.nd.array(frame)

        img_tf, _ = gcv.data.transforms.presets.ssd.transform_test(frame, short=512)
        frame = frame.asnumpy().astype('uint8')
        frame = cv2.resize(frame, (910, 512))

        class_IDs, scores, detections = net(img_tf.copyto(ctx))

        class_IDs = class_IDs.squeeze().asnumpy()
        scores = scores.squeeze().asnumpy()
        detections = detections.squeeze().asnumpy()

        predicts = []        
        for idx, det in enumerate(detections):
            xmin, ymin, xmax, ymax = det
            if scores[idx] > 0.5 and xmin + (xmax - xmin) / 2 < counting_point + 10:
            # if scores[idx] > 0.5 and ymin + (ymax - ymin) / 2 < counting_point + 10:
                predicts.append({"id": class_IDs[idx], "score": scores[idx], "bbox": list(det)})

        updated_tracks = []

        for obj in tracks_active:
            # update information of vehicle
            if len(predicts) > 0:

                best_match = max(predicts, key=lambda x: iou(obj["bbox"], x["bbox"]))

                if iou(obj["bbox"], best_match["bbox"]) >= 0.5:
                    obj["bbox"] = best_match["bbox"]
                    if best_match["score"] > obj["score"]:
                        obj["score"] = best_match["score"]
                        obj["id"] = best_match["id"]
                    xmin, ymin, xmax, ymax = obj["bbox"]
                    if xmin + (xmax - xmin) / 2 > counting_point and obj["is_counted"] == False: 
                    # if ymin + (ymax - ymin) / 2 > counting_point and obj["is_counted"] == False: 
                        nof_vehicle[int(obj["id"])] += 1
                        obj["is_counted"] = True
                    updated_tracks.append(obj)
                    del predicts[predicts.index(best_match)]

        new_objects = [{"id": pred["id"], "score": pred["score"], "bbox": pred["bbox"], "is_counted": False} for pred in predicts]
        tracks_active = updated_tracks + new_objects
        bboxes = []
        ids = []

        for track in tracks_active:
            if (track["is_counted"] == False):
                bboxes.append(track["bbox"])
                ids.append(int(track["id"]))

        bboxes = np.array(bboxes)
        ids = np.array(ids)
        colors = {0: (82, 7, 242), 1: (215, 242, 5)}

        frame = gcv.utils.viz.cv_plot_bbox(frame, bboxes, labels=ids, class_names=classes, colors=colors)

        frame_number += 1

        cv2.line(frame, (counting_point, 0), (counting_point, 512), (0, 255, 0), 2)
        for i in range(len(classes)):
            text = "{} : {:d}".format(classes[i], nof_vehicle[i])
            cv2.putText(frame, text, (10, 20 * (i + 1)), cv2.FONT_HERSHEY_SIMPLEX, 0.6, (0, 0, 0), 1)
        out.write(frame)
    end = time.time()
    print("Total time: {}".format(end - start))
    print("FPS: {}",format(frame_number / (end - start)))
    cap.release()
    out.release()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

I'm not sure what the error means.

```
Unable to init server: Could not connect: Connection refused
Unable to init server: Could not connect: Connection refused

(vehicle.py:12794): Gdk-CRITICAL **: 08:57:21.070: gdk_cursor_new_for_display: assertion 'GDK_IS_DISPLAY (display)' failed
/home/hangnguyen/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/mxnet/gluon/block.py:1389: UserWarning: Cannot decide type for the following arguments. Consider providing them as input:
        data: None
  input_sym_arg_type = in_param.infer_type()[0]
terminate called after throwing an instance of 'dmlc::Error'
  what():  [08:57:21] src/ndarray/ndarray.cc:1288: GPU is not enabled
Stack trace:
  [bt] (0) /home/hangnguyen/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/mxnet/libmxnet.so(+0x307d3b) [0x7f365b03dd3b]
  [bt] (1) /home/hangnguyen/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/mxnet/libmxnet.so(mxnet::CopyFromTo(mxnet::NDArray const&, mxnet::NDArray const&, int, bool)+0x6db) [0x7f365e31628b]
```

I tried looking it up on google and StackOverflow, but it seems like no one has this error. The closest article I can found is [this one](https://github.com/apache/incubator-mxnet/issues/15281), but I already have mxnet 1.6 installed. I'm running this code on a remote server, is that the problem?

Could anyone help me out? Thank you so much.

Answer (score 0):

You can try installing this library and check

```
pip install opencv-contrib-python
```